# Get count of Observable array before returning it

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

In my ViewModel file I have an observable array created after applying map on it. Now before returning it I want to check if it has any content or not. If there is nothing in there I want to return it without applying map. Following is my code:

```
func retrieveDeals(location: CLLocation?) -> Observable<[SaleItem]> {
    let specials = nearestFlightSpecials.retrieveNearestFlightSpecials(userLocation: location)
    let happyHourDeals = specials.map {
        $0.filter { $0.isHappyHour }
    }
    return happyHourDeals
}
```

Before I return happyHourDeals I want to check if it contains any element or not. The above array is subscribed in view but I don't want to apply the above logic there. I want to keep it here in ViewModel.

Comment: If the array is empty nothing will be done really when calling `map` so I see no gain in changing your code. If you insist on checking then use `isEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want to do is filter out empty output:

```
func retrieveDeals(location: CLLocation?) -> Observable<[SaleItem]> {
    let specials = nearestFlightSpecials.retrieveNearestFlightSpecials(userLocation: location)
    let happyHourDeals = specials.map {
        $0.filter { $0.isHappyHour }
    }
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty } // this is the line you need.
    return happyHourDeals
}
```

Terminology is important here. Observables don't "contain" values. Observables don't return values, they emit events.

Your `happyHourDeals` will still be returned but with the `filter` line, it will no longer emit empty arrays. What this means is that whatever is subscribed to the value returned will not be updated if `specials.map { $0.filter { $0.isHappyHour } }` emits an empty array.